# Errors after installing mongodb 2.4.14 and mysql

Tags: mysql, mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed mongodb 2.4.14 using [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) guide.
But After Installing the mongodb I'm getting the errors just before completion. I have searched a lot but unable to eliminate those errors. Below is the error

> initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
>   insserv: warning: script 'mongodb' missing LSB tags and overrides
>   insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `mongodb'
>   insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script`mongodb'
>   initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
>   insserv: warning: script 'mongodb' missing LSB tags and overrides
>   insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `mongodb'
>   insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script`mongodb'

And after installing mysql I am also getting errors

> Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
>   initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
>   insserv: warning: script 'mongodb' missing LSB tags and overrides
>   insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `mongodb'
>   insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script`mongodb'
>   Setting up mysql-server (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
>   Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
>   Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu11) ...
>   Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the upstart has replaced the init prior to ubuntu 15 so either you can edit the upstart script or you can install 14.04